# Display a message after RedirectToAction in Asp.Net Mvc 4?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In one control there is the following code,

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(M m, HttpPostedFileBase photo)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Details", new {id});
```

How to display a message in `Details` view just for `Create`? (e.g. a message shows "The new record has been created." at the top of the page). Other controls may redirect to the view too and they may show different messages or none.

Do it have something like `ModelState.AddModelError` for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a querystring parameter `success=true` and show a message in Create if it exists, or you could set a cookie before you send the `RedirectToAction` response and test it (and clear it) in the Create action, or process it from a client script.